# How to update my Asterisk Dial-Plan for combination of Telephone Number?

Tags: linux, asterisk, telecommunication

I am trying to create dialplan for incoming/outgoing for given numbers:

> +xx xxx [xxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxx]

I have already configure my service provider information in `sip.conf`

```
[sipprovider]
type=friend
secret=xxxxx
defaultusername=xxxxx
host=xxx.xx.xx.xxx
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm
insecure=port,invite
;fromdomain=xxx.xx.xx.xxx
context=default
nat=yes
```

Now, I want to create incoming/outgoing trunk, my extensions allow to dial international calls and incoming call received on given number.

> +xx xxx [xxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxx]

```
[default]
    switch => Realtime

    exten => 55,1,Verbose(1,Echo test application)
    exten => 55,n,Dial(SIP/sipprovider/0091XXXXX99999@sipprovider); Here is the outbound call, the exact dialstring depends on outgoing provider and channeltype
    exten => 55,n,Hangup()
```

Display: Calling....
and then, VM Play: `Person you are calling is unavailable`

Asterisk Console:

```
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [55@default:1] Verbose("SIP/3001-00000029", "1,Echo test application") in new stack
 Echo test application
    -- Executing [55@default:2] Dial("SIP/3001-00000029", "SIP/sipprovider/0091XXXXX99999@sipprovider") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/sipprovider/0091XXXXX99999@sipprovider
[Aug 17 18:29:02] WARNING[32467]: chan_sip.c:4024 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission 78a9b28011fd522601047c9317adca91@xx.xx.xx.xx:5060 for seqno 102 (Critical Request) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 32000ms with no response
[Aug 17 18:29:02] WARNING[32467]: chan_sip.c:4053 retrans_pkt: Hanging up call 78a9b28011fd522601047c9317adca91@xx.xx.xx.xx:5060 - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Executing [55@default:3] Hangup("SIP/3001-00000029", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (default, 55, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/3001-00000029'
    -- Executing [h@default:1] Verbose("SIP/3001-00000029", "Hangup...") in new stack
Hangup...
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically a dialstring can be in 'SIP/devicename/extension' or 'SIP/username@host' format. `SIP/sipprovider/0091XXXXX99999@sipprovider` is wrong.

"Retransmission timeout reached" means that asterisk tries to send an INVITE to sipprovider, but sipprovider's SIP port (`5060 UDP`) isn't accessible. You can see this in SIP debug.

Comment: Thank for quick respone, As in my case `sipprovider` in sip.conf file added with host details and added in dial-plan as `SIP/sipprovider/${EXTEN}` as Outgoing is not working not, as you told 5060 UDP is n't accesible for that. I need to do any configuration in Firewall / NAT in linux?

Comment: You can `ping sipprovider`. If there are responses, you can contact your sipproviders support and ask if they see SIP packets when you try to call via this trunk.